# How can I use Ionics 'on-release' for a input range value, in case of multiple range inputs and ng-repeat?

Tags: input, range, multi-touch, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I'am using Angular.js and Ionic Framework. Is it possible to use 'on-release' for multiple range inputs at the same time when using ng-repeat?

It works fine for one touch, but when using two ranges simultaneously only the first one returns to the value 0 on release.

Here is my example.

html

```
<div class="list">
<div ng-repeat="range in ranges" class="range">
    <input on-release="onRelease(range)" type="range" ng-model="range.value">
    <p>{{range.value}}</p>
</div>
```

controller

```
$scope.ranges = [
{
    'value': 0
},
{
    'value': 0
},
{
    'value': 0
}];
```

`$scope.onRelease = function (range) {
    range.value = 0;
};`

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `ng-bind`. See the following solution.

```
<div class="range range-energized">
    <i class="icon ion-ios-circle-outline yellow"></i>
    <input type="range" name="data[MyModel][rating]" ng-model="data.MyModel.rating" min="0" max="5" value="0" tabindex="2">
    <i class="icon ion-record yellow"></i>
</div>
<div class="row row-responsive-med">
    <div class="col col-center col-100">
        <small class="CoreCircus subdued">Rating</small>&nbsp;<small class="CoreCircus"><span ng-bind="data.MyModel.rating"></span><span ng-if="!data.MyModel.rating">0</span>/{{maxRating}}</small>
    </div>
</div>
```